# How to run an action at a specific time - Rails Heroku server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am working on building a Rails-based Internet of Things platform where certain devices are manipulated at certain predetermined times.  I am having difficulty running actions at specific times, however, because Heroku's built-in Scheduling library seems to only support callbacks at constant intervals.  My server needs to make calls at arbitrary times with no future repetition. Are there any other gems or methods in Rails that can serve this function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [delyed job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem. Make use of the `run_at` field to run your task at specific times.
Here is an example

```
class LongTasks
  def send_mailer
    # Some other code
  end
  handle_asynchronously :send_mailer, :priority => 20

  def in_the_future
    # Some other code
  end
  # 5.minutes.from_now will be evaluated when in_the_future is called
  handle_asynchronously :in_the_future, :run_at => Proc.new { 5.minutes.from_now }

  def self.when_to_run
    2.hours.from_now
  end

  class << self
    def call_a_class_method
      # Some other code
    end
    handle_asynchronously :call_a_class_method, :run_at => Proc.new { when_to_run }
  end

  attr_reader :how_important

  def call_an_instance_method
    # Some other code
  end
  handle_asynchronously :call_an_instance_method, :priority => Proc.new {|i| i.how_important }
end
```